# Adding a Library to the Library Browser

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a difficulty. I can not add a library "FOTS Simulator" to the  Simulink Library Browser in MATLAB.

I was reading the site "https://www.goddardconsulting.ca/simulink-creating-custom-libraries.html" but I cannot reproduce their result.

In my computer I have installed MATLAB in :

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a
```

And I  created a "FOTS Simulator" folder. In this folder are several files, including "Slblocks". So this file is in:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\FOTS Simulator
```

I ran `slblock.m` in a directory that is on the MATLAB path. However, I wrote `Browser.Library = 'FOTS_2015a'` (as you can see in the code below).
It should be noted that this file (FOTS_2015a)  is in `.slx` format in :

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\FOTS Simulator
```

How do I make  "FOTS Simulator"   appear in the  Library Browser?

Code:

```
function BlkStruct = slblocks
   BlkStruct.Name = sprintf('FOTS Simulator')    
   Browser.IsFlat  = 1;
   BlkStruct.OpenFcn = 'FOTS_2015a'
   Browser.Library = 'FOTS_2015a';
   BlkStruct.MaskDisplay = ''
   Browser.Name = 'FOTS Simulator';
   % 'OFTS Simulator' is the library name that appears in the Library Browser
   BlkStruct.Browser = Browser; 
end
```

Comment: (The steps at the link you give work - I've just gone through them with a newly created library to check.)  What do you mean by `I ran slblock.m in a directory that is on the MATLAB path`?  You shouldn't be running that file at all.  If it is in a directory that in on the MATLAB path then it will automatically get executed by Simulink when the library browser is openned.  You shouldn't be executing it yourself.

Comment: Thank you Phill for your response. The "Slblocks" file is in a directory that is in the path of MATLAB .... it is in "C: \ Program Files \ MATLAB \ MATLAB Production Server \ R2015a \ toolbox \ FOTS Simulator". However, how it was not automatically run by Simulink when the library browser is open, so I ran slblock.m to try. Did you run the "slblock" file and appear in the library? Why get not I?

Comment: You should not be running `slblocks` manually your self.  It is executed automatically.  Is your directory permanently on the MATLAB path, or are you adding it manually each time you start MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Many of the following steps are over-kill and not required, nonetheless I would suggest doing the following:

1. Close MATLAB
2. Start MATLAB
3. Remove your directory from the MATLAB path, saving the change so that it is permanently removed.
4. Close MATLAB
5. move or rename your `slbocks.m` file (so that effectively `slblocks.m` for your custom library doesn't exist)
6. Start MATLAB (do ***not*** cd into your directory)
7. Try to open your custom Simulink library by typing its name at the MATLAB command line.  This should generate an error saying the library cannot be found.  If the library can be found then go back to step 3.
8. Add your directory to the MATLAB path, saving the change so that it is permanently on the path.
9. Try to open your custom Simulink library by typing its name at the MATLAB command line.  This should open your library.  If it doesn't then for some reason MATLAB is not finding your library.
10. Close MATLAB
11. create `slblocks.m` for your custom library putting it in your directory
12. Start MATLAB
13. Start Simulink (by opening a model or creating one from scratch)
14. Open the Simulink Library browser

Your custom library should appear in the list of available libraries.

Comment: Thank you Phil,
I followed your steps:
1- OK;
2-OK;
3-OK. I removed "FOTS Simulator" in path "C: \ Program Files \ MATLAB \ MATLAB Production Server \ R2015a \ toolbox \ FOTS Simulator";
4-OK;
5-I moved slblocks.m file;
6-OK;
7-I think that here is the my first problem. I  open the Simulink library. I think  it's general Simulink library(or default Simulimk library) instead custom Simulink library.
It´s hard that "FOTS simulator" to appear inserted ... such as what is in the figure example  that I sent to your email.

Comment: Joao, please accept the answer if the steps solved your problem.

Comment: I  not solved the problem after point 6.
I think that here is the my first problem in the point 7. I open the Simulink library. I think it's general Simulink library(or default Simulimk library) instead custom Simulink library. It´s hard that "FOTS simulator" to appear inserted ... such as what is in the figure example that I sent to your email.

Comment: Please upload the image as edit to your question and indicate why it is not correct.

Comment: I wanted to see as a final result what is  in the link 7yce4x.s.cld.pt . How do I do this? 
I followed your steps but in step 7 I have a problem. I open the Simulink library. I think it's general Simulink library(or default Simulimk library)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again,

In this moment, my simulink library browser  it's what's in the link below: https://j3v70r.s.cld.pt

I want with the file  "slblock.m" to make to appear in the simulink library "Fots Simulator" as it appears in the example of the link below:
https://7yce4x.s.cld.pt

I did your steps but I got not do it from step 7 (including).

When you tried my example, in your simulink library  the "Fots Simulator"  did  appear according to the link above?

Can you help me?

Comment: At Step 7 you should be trying (and failing) to open your **custom** Simulink library.  From your comment above you seem to be indicating that you are opening the standard Simulink library (which should be found, and you should be able to open.)  If at Step 7 you can open your **custom** library then it must be in a directory that is on the MATLAB path, in which case you haven't done Step 3.

Comment: I understand that there are custom and standard Simulink library. In the step 7 you say:"Try to open your custom Simulink library by typing its name at the MATLAB command line..."
I have doubts:
- What should I write at the MATLAB command line?
- How to create custom library from what I have (folder with slblocks.m, FOTS_2015.slx, multiple png format files, etc...)?

Comment: You should type the name of your library and press return.

Comment: I'll send you what I have and check if you get add foots simualtor in the Simulink library.